# Stop When EOF On Line Python

Tags: python, input

I am reading in lines using the following code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print('Output: ', end='')
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

As I type I see output such as:

```
test
Output: test
another test
Output: another test
eof at end of line^DOutput: eof at end of line
I can still type here
Output: I can still type here
...
```

In this instance `^D` means typing CTRL-D or the EOF character.

My program should end when an EOF occurs at the end of a line not just when it is the only character in a line. How can I get this behavior?

Example behavior:

```
test
Output: test
another test
Output: another test
eof at end of line^DOutput: eof at end of line
[program terminates]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your operating system, but I'll lay odds it's LINUX or another UNIX variant.

The trick here is that ^D isn't really itself the EOF marker. Instead, the driver reading the input identifies the ^D as signaling the end of file and so closes the file connecting the terminal to your program, producing the EOF condition.

The kicker, though, is that the driver ONLY interprets ^D when it's the first character in the line, in case someone actually wants to be able to type ^D. So, this is going to be harder to do, but it's not that there's a problem in your program --you're just seeing unexpected but normal behavior.

Comment: The terminal driver does not close the stream, and it does always interpret `^D`.  But it just makes `read(2)` return, which only implies EOF when it returns 0.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the behavior that I want? I know in C I can use something like `while (getline(&line, &n, stdin) != -1)` and this will produce my expected behavior.